# Google Drive SDK File.getFileSize() NullPointerException

Tags: java, google-drive-api

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Using the newest Google Drive `SDK v2-rev25-1.12.0`
- Retrieve the list of files using the LIST `API` of `Google Drive`
- You should have now a `List<File>`
- Looping trough the list read the file size with `File.getFileSize()`
- Folders and files with extensions work ok, you get the file size `0` or something `> 0`
- Call `getFileSize` on `GoogleDocs` Files stored in the Google Drive produce a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

File size on google native documents have no real meaning for the end user, because he will never download a file having the native format of google docs. You may have an idea of the space occupied on the user's drive using the quotaBytesUsed property of File.

By the way, are you sure you get a NPE when you call file.getFileSize() or when you use the result of this invokation in other method ? Because such a call should return `null` but should not throw an `Exception`